# How to find if a key, if dont exist add in the key with value, if exist do update the value in Meteor + mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to update my `quiz_score`, if the `qnNumber` not exist i want to push in the `qnNumber` as key and `selectedAnsNum` as value and if it exist i want to just update the value

```
let quiz_score = {}
    quiz_score[qnNumber] = selectedAnsNum
    Meteor.users.update({
        _id: Meteor.userId(),
        "course_learn_list.course_id": courseId
    }, {
        $addToSet: {
            "course_learn_list.$.quiz_score": {
                quiz_score
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: I've not used Meteor, but in Mongo you can pass the `upsert` flag to do an insert if the record you're trying to update doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with `meteor`, here is just sample code under mongo shell. To meet your requirement, I think it could be done through those following two command. You could convert them into meteor command.

```
// if we find the match course, update this one through `$set`
db.users.update({_id: id, 'course_learn_list.course_id': courseId},
    {$set: {'course_learn_list.$': {course_id: courseId, quiz_score: quiz_score}}});

// if we cannot find match course, insert this new one through `$addToSet`
db.users.update({_id: id, 'course_learn_list.course_id': {$ne: courseId}}, { 
    {$addToSet: {course_learn_list: {course_id: courseId, quiz_score: quiz_score}}});
```